# Mysql error when I try to persist to the database - Symfony2 - possible Date error?

Tags: php, date, symfony, mysql-error-1064

I have following code:

```
$dateCounter=1;

    foreach($teamsA as $teamHome){
        foreach($teamsACopy as $teamAway){
            if($teamHome!=$teamAway){
                $tactic1 = $doctrine->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Tactics')
                        ->findByteamTeamid($teamHome->getTeamid());
                $tactic2 = $doctrine->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Tactics')
                        ->findByteamTeamid($teamAway->getTeamid());
                $match = new Match();
                $match->setAwayteam($teamAway->getName());
                $match->setHometeam($teamHome->getName());
                $match->setIsplayed(false);
                $match->setSeasonSeasonid($season);
                $date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$dateCounter.'D'));
                $match->setDate($date);
                $dateCounter++;
                $tacticMatchHome = new Tactics();
                $tacticMatchHome = $tactic1[0];
                $tacticMatchHome->setMatchMatchid($match);
                $tacticMatchAway = new Tactics();
                $tacticMatchAway = $tactic2[0];
                $tacticMatchAway->setMatchMatchid($match);
                $em->persist($match);
                $em->flush();
                $em->persist($tacticMatchHome);
                $em->flush();
                $em->persist($tacticMatchAway);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I get the following error when it tries to persist it to the database:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO match (date, homeTeam, awayTeam, winner, isPlayed, score, season_seasonid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2014-11-16 13:50:24", "FC Beer", "Soccerteam11", null, 0, null, 9]:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or acces violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match (date, homeTeam, awayTeam, winner, isPlayed, score, season_seasonid) VALUE' at line1
```

Is it possible that I get this error because my date isn't in a correct format? If so, how can I convert it to the proper format?

I'm using Symfony2 and PHP version 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change table name match to other - it's a reserved word.
Don't create new object only for code completion.
replace `$tacticMatchHome = new Tactics();` with `/** @var $tacticMatchHome Tactics */`.
And use findOneBy instead of findBy ;)
And finally, you can flush once at the end of code.

Comment: Because in next line you're setting another object to this variable. Creating new object only for code completion it's not a good practice in performance aspect and in general "clean-code" aspect :)

Answer (score 1):

`match` is a MySQL reserved keyword. If you're going to name a table "match" you *must* wrap it in ticks:

```
'INSERT INTO `match` (date, homeTeam, awayTeam, winner, isPlayed, score, season_seasonid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
```

Comment: And to have Symphony do that when it builds a query (it doesn’t do so automatically), either the backticks have to be included in the data definition already, or a `QuoteStrategy` has to be used: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words